# How come JAX-WS doesn't need a Web Container

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, jax-ws

I have earlier used Jersey API to build JSON web services and deploy them on Tomcat/Websphere.

I am now trying to create a JAX-WS SOAP service and I assumed that Tomcat would be involved.

From this tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/), it looks like I don't need a web server to run a JAX-WS service!

1. How come full-fledged web server is not required for JAX-WS which serves data on HTTP?
2. Is it possible to run the service on Tomcat/Websphere? Update: Found an example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/)
3. Are there any disadvantages/advantages of using a proper web server (as compared to the inbuilt endpoint publisher)?

Edited:

- Are there any disadvantages of using the embedded HttpServer? Will
  JAX-WS implementation use servlet-pool etc to optimise simultaneous
  service calls?
- If it was regular servlets I could use Security
  filters, Log filters etc. Does endpoint implementation provide
  alternate mechanism for intercepting requests?
- Is it ok to use the embedded HttpServer in production?

Comment: JSE ships with a lightweight embedded http server (in the form of [`HttpServer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html)). `Endpoint` is *not* a server impl

Answer (score 0):

A web server is required, either an embedded or stand alone. Here the `Endpoint` class acts as a lightweight embedded HTTP server (or a subset of one at least).

Comment: In the article (step no.3), he mentions creating a publisher class with a "main" method. Looks like it needs to be run as "Java Application" on Eclipse. This is the only line in the main method: Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());

Comment: Ah missed that. There the `Endpoint` class is acting as an embedded HTTP server (of sorts).